# How can use topologymanager obsolete Namespace in Custom SharePoint Web Service?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2007

I am unable to Use the Topologymanager class inside the namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Topology. I searched a lot. Its urgent. Thanks

**I am getting the following error. When I include the namespace "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Topology" in my Custom Web service.**

> A runtime exception was detected.
>   Details follow.  Message: Cannot open
>   database "WSS_Content_Dev3" requested
>   by the login. The login failed. Login
>   failed for user
>
> Techinal Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Cannot open database
>   "WSS_Content_Dev3" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. Login failed
>   for user .
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64
>   timerExpire, SqlConnection
>   owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String
>   host, String newPassword, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, Object
>   providerInfo, String newPassword,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory
>   connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.OpenConnection()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand
>   command)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Data.SqlDatabaseManager.HasAccess(String
>   user)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.SynchronizeAccessControl(SharedComponentSecurity
>   sharedApplicationSecurity)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.SharedResourceProvider.Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ISharedComponent.Synchronize()

---

---

---

Comment: is this due to this? Obtaining the SharePoint Site Context  [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583131(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: When I copy the web service dll into my Hosted site then it works. I am not able to find the exact solution.The _vti_bin/bin virtual directory is mapped to the \\Server_Name\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\ISAPI directory (not working)

Comment: for this I have to Add the SharePoint Server Patch to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally got the solution:**

When you Use the templogymanager inside the web service directly or even include the namespace "Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Topology" at the top of the custom web service. It gives you error. I did the following thing.

1. I create the helper project in which I used the namespace ***Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Toplogy***.
2. Compile it and put the dll into ***GAC***.
3. Add the .dll reference to my project.
4. Then I called the helper Method in my custom web service.
5. ***Problem Solve.***